# How does Oracle 12c handle Time Zone data in DATE datatype

Tags: oracle, date, timezone, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle Database 12c. I want to know how oracle manages timezone details for DATE datatype.

1. If i were to migrate data between time zones can i still get away with using DATE datatype? Or do i have to use TimeStamp or TimeStamp with TimeZone?
2. Does it keep the UTC time in DB and convert it when querying for results according to session time zone or some other NLS setting?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, data type `DATE` does not handle any time zone information. Use data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`

`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` holds date + time + time zone

`TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` holds date + time and these are stored internally in `DBTIMEZONE` (typically `UTC`). The value is **always** shown in the current user session time zone `SESSIONTIMEZONE`.

If you like to convert a `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP WITH {LOCAL} TIME ZONE`, then you must tell Oracle which time zone shall be used.

Typically you do it like this:

```
FROM_TZ(CAST({date_value} AS TIMESTAMP), 'desired time zone')
```

The cast is required because `FROM_TZ` requires a `TIMESTAMP` rather than a `DATE`

If you don't specify the time zone, e.g. like `CAST({date_value} AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)` then Oracle defaults the time zone to `SESSIONTIMEZONE`

Comment: So in simple terms if i were to migrate my data using DATE datatype to a db in a different timezone it won't change anything when viewing the data including the time portion. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the time zone of the DB does not have any influence on any `DATE` value